# Android TV - Android TV Box is not detected as a TV (UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tv

When I test my app on:

- **TV Emulators:** Behaves as expected, banner appears and I get the "TV" App.
- **Android Box (Wetek Play 2, Lolipop 5.1.1):** "non-TV" app and no banner.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

<application
    android:name="removed"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:banner="@mipmap/banner"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashAppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

I also have this function which returns **true** on the emulator and **false** on the box:

```
public boolean isTvApp() {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);

    boolean isTvAsRecommendedByGoogle = uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION;
    @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
    boolean isTv01 = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 21 && pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEVISION);
    boolean isTv02 = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LIVE_TV);
    boolean hasTouchScreen = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN);
    boolean hasLeanback = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK);

    return
            isTvAsRecommendedByGoogle ||
            isTv01 ||
            isTv02 ||
            !hasTouchScreen ||
            hasLeanback;

}
```

**How can I get the banner to work/show on the android box?**

**How can I get isTvApp() to work for the android box?**

Comment: can you debug that which parameters are false on the box?

Comment: Debug how?  I have debugged/walked through my code, and all the parameters I check for UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION/FEATURE_TELEVISION/etc return false.  (Except touchscreen, that returns true.  Despite not having a touchscreen.)  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that

`UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION == false`
`FEATURE_TELEVISION == false`
`FEATURE_LIVE_TV == false`
`FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN == true`

is because (most?) android boxes have the potential to use a mouse (and keyboard).

The mouse basically provides the functionality of a touch screen.

---

*I believe* we need to think of the android box as more of a computer than a TV-app box.

I'm pretty sure Android box manufacturers set `FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN == true` (despite not having a touchscreen) so that their users can have access to **all** apps (instead of just apps that have `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />`).

With this is mind, I'm not sure whether it would be best to treat all Android Boxes as if it were Android TV or not.  (You might be restricting features to those who actually use it like a computer).